# User posting wrong question title because title already exists

Tags: discussion, questions, users, quality-improvement, behavior

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964674/erro-in-javascript). I tried to correct the spelling in that question title, and then I came to know that the title already exists. So the user-typed question title is like "Erro in JavaScript". Is there a way to handle this type of scenario or just edit it to some other meaningful question title by reading his post?

[image]

### Update:

Now he updated the title: **"Error in my JavaScript"**

Comment: Titles show be meaningful and should provide a hint. "*Error in my Javascript*" is bad. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It is always a good idea to edit a topic title to make it clear, explicit and meaningful.

Comment: Just update the title and leave a good comment of why you have made those changes.

Comment: @Joe Thanx Joe for editing it instead of behaving like Rahul

Comment: @Navy no problem. I don't think Rahul was trying to be malicious with this post. Meta is here to help people and learn more about the site, don't take it personally, it is a valid question to ask.

Comment: @Joe: It's _number_ of times, not _amount_ of times.

Comment: @TheBlueDog oh.my.god. I hate myself for even typing that. Good catch!

Comment: @Joe: That's ok, my ex-girfriend is from Yorkshire - she didn't speak proper English either. ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog I'm not actually from York, I originate from Norfolk (so I say a lot of grammatically incorrect things without even realising... at least that's my excuse and I'm sticking to it!)

Comment: @Joe: Mate, I'm originally from Essex so I'm surprised that I can even use a computer! ;)

Answer (score 16):

Even if you edit the title, `Error in my Javascript` is not even a meaningful title too, so in that case you better comment and suggest to the OP to clarify the title and the question, because the most important thing here is to teach people [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good and concise question so better **comment it and recommend an Edit**.

And if you see that it's really intended to be like this:

- [Downvote the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).
- [Flag it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), so it can be reviewed.

Because the main purpose in the site is to only keep relevant and concise content, by ***avoiding*** **duplicates** and **low quality posts**.

Comment: Are you suggesting that questions with bad titles should be flagged? With which flag option?

Comment: @2mkgz No, I'm not saying that *all questions with bad titles should be flagged* I just said that if you see that this behaviour is intended and meant to be like this, you can flag it so it **needs a moderator attention** or flag it as a **low-quality post** so it can peer reviewed, and no my first suggestion was to **Edit** or to **leave a comment**.